# PyQt5: Center align a label

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This should be really simple but I just can't find an answer for this.
I've tried this PyQt4 code:

```
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Do any of the other alignment flags work? For instance, can you right align the label (using `Qt.AlignRight`), or bottom align the label (using `Qt.AlignBottom`)?

Comment: Works for me like a charm. But I use PySide, maybe PyQt4 has a problem there although unlikely.

Comment: @three_pineapples Nope.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm using PyQt5, the example is from PyQt4.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in PyQt5. Stylesheets might be a workaround.

Comment: @Trilarion I've tried to find out how to do aligning with stylesheets in PyQt5 but I can't find an answer >_<

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe, is your QLabel widget big enough and maybe expanding in the layout, to actually have enough space to center the text? Can you show small runnable example?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the problem may be that the label is centered, but it does not fill the space you think it does. You can verify by changing the label background color. The following example works for me on Windows 7:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.label = QLabel("Test", self)
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: red;}")

        self.button = QPushButton("Test", self)

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

Try using:

```
Qt.Qt.AlignCenter.
```

Answer (score 8):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

# to center align a label 

self.your_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

For more information, please follow the following StackOverflow thread:
[Qt has no attribute 'AlignCenter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877172/qt-has-no-attribute-aligncenter/41877173)

Answer (score 3):

The value of AlignCenter was defined at `PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter`,
the other Align value was also define at `QtCore.Qt`.
`QtCore.Qt` Module also contain core value such as keyboard value CTRL, SHIFT, ALT etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a workaround with HTML translating!

```
self.smallPWDisp.setText(_translate('Window', '<html><head/><body><p align=\'center\'>%s is your new password!</p></body></html>' % smallPassword))
```