# Qt has no attribute 'AlignCenter'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 on Python 3.5.

I want to make a `QLabel` widget with a centered text. Therefore, I call the `setAlignment` method with the `AlignCenter` flag.

Here is an MWE:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, Qt

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

However, I get the following error:

> label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
>
> AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.Qt' has no attribute 'AlignCenter'

But the `Qt.AlignCenter`, as well as other alignment flags, are referenced in [PyQt's documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum), as well as [Qt's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am posting this question along with the solution I found. This might be a really specific case, and I probably got in this situation because I read the documentation too hastily. However, I do believe that the naming is confusing, and I want to help people who might get in the same situation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `AttributeError` that is raised tells that `PyQt5.Qt` has no attribute called `AlignCenter`.

This can easily be confirmed in Python's interactive help:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import Qt
>>> help(Qt)
```

`help` will display a bunch of methods, but a quick search of "alignment" will give zero results.

As a matter of fact, the `AlignCenter` flag does not belong to the `PyQt5.Qt` module, but to the `PyQt5.QtCore.Qt` class.

Therefore, changing

```
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
```

into

```
label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

along with the right import will do the work.

---

The following code shows that this actually works. I had to add some details to the original code to make the centering visible.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
label.setText("Hello world!")
label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

label.show()

exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Centered text label]

With the alignment commented out:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
label.setText("Hello world!")
# label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

label.show()

exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Untouched label]

Comment: Leaving this here as a comment for any confused PyQt6 porters:
`QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter` would be the syntax for PyQt6

Comment: 'Cursors' object has no attribute 'RESIZE_HORIZONTAL' is what I get with %matplotlib qt. It seems similar. Could you advise me ?

Comment: Thanks, this was a really confusing snag.